# paper.js create line path over raster image not working

Tags: javascript, paperjs

First time using `paper.js` and trying to allow the user to free hand draw a line over a raster image. The image loads OK but none of the Mouse events fire.

I load my image like this:

```
function loadImage($url, $type = 'load') {

    var $width, $height;

    var $image = new Image();
    $image.src = $url;

    $image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

        var $size = resizeImage($image);
        $width = $size.width;
        $height = $size.height;

        $($canvas).hide();

        if ($type == 'load') {
            paper.project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
            paper.view.draw();
        }

        $raster = new paper.Raster({
            source: $image.src,
            position: view.center,
        });

        if ($image.width > $image.height) {
            $raster.rotate(90);
            $width = $size.height;
            $height = $size.width;
        }

        paper.view.viewSize = new Size($width, $height);
        $raster.fitBounds(paper.view.bounds);

        $canvas.width = $width;
        $canvas.height = $height;

        $($canvas).fadeIn('slow');

    };

}
```

I then have the following mouse events:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    console.log('onMouseDown');

    if ($path) {
        path.selected = false;
    }

    $path = new Path({
        segments: [event.point],
        strokeColor: '#ff0000',
        strokeWidth: 5,
    });
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    console.log('onMouseDrag');
    $path.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    console.log('onMouseUp');
    $path.fullySelected = true;
}
```

But the events do not fire. What did I miss? Thanks.

Comment: These events will only fire inside `PaperScript` context and I guess that you are using `Paper.js` in `JavaScript` context. Try binding your events to the `view`: `view.onMouseDown = function(event){...};`. If this doesn't work, please try to reproduce your issue in a fiddle so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your event-handlers to the current paper view.

```
paper.view.onMouseDown = onMouseDown;
paper.view.onMouseUp = onMouseUp;
```

look at: http://paperjs.org/reference/view/